# data not display with Link in React Js with React-router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm implementing a navigation in React Js with React Router version 6, when I use the  composent it doesn't work, I get a blank page. THANKS

My `Header` Component:

[image]

My `App` component:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the routes themselves, try adding / in front https://i.imgur.com/yspKaz7.png

Comment: @Levi also put your codes into text not images!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is beacuse you are using components that is not inmported like

And also you have to put BrowserRouter component at the very top level